# Fastest Way to Update Rows in a Large Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have one doubt in sql server 
Basically I need to run this on a table with 60 million rows, updating every row at once will crash, so I want to batch the query so that if it crash, it can re-run the query and it would skip the finished batch and just continue with the ones left over.

I want updated emp table data with refernce of empref table.here both table have millons of records ,but i am providign some sample data in the below.

while update time we need to splits batches with top clause and should not repeat existing top.

sample tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
) 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empref](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (1, N'a', 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (2, N'b', 200)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (4, N'u', 300)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (7, N'x', 400)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (8, N't', 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (1, N'xx', 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (2, N'bb', 200)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (4, N'uu', 300)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (7, N'xxx', 400)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (8, N'tt', 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empref] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (10, N'ub', 600)
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
emp:
id  |name|sal
1   |xx |100
2   |bb |200
4   |uu |300
7   |xxx|400
8   |tt |500
```

---

I tried like below :

```
declare @i int
 set @i=1

 while ( @i <= (select max(id) from emp ))

 begin 
 update  TOP(2)  t  set t.name=s.name 
 from emp t join empref s  on t.id=s.id 
 print @@rowcount

 set @i=@i+1
 end
```

above  update query is updated only that top 2 records only and its not getting next top 2  records  update query is not iterated .
its always updated only that top 2 records only.

please tell me how to create multiple batches using while loop  in sql server .

Comment: How does you "Update every row at once" SQL statement that you say crashed look? And how does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say this will be the fastest approach but the reason why the `WHILE LOOP` is selecting the same two rows is because you need to also need track the `Id` column on the `Emp` table

Assuming the `Id` column is an `Identity` column with no gaps

```
DECLARE @i  INT, @TrackId INT
SET @i = 1;
SET @TrackId = (SELECT  MIN(Id) FROM emp)
SELECT @TrackId

WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM emp))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempEmp TABLE ( Id INT, [name] VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp
    (Id ,[name] )
    SELECT TOP 2 E.Id, [E].[name]
    FROM dbo.emp E
    WHERE E.Id >= @TrackId
    ORDER BY E.Id ASC

    UPDATE 
        t
    SET t.[name] = s.[name]
    FROM dbo.emp t
    JOIN @tempEmp TE ON TE.Id = t.id
    JOIN empref s ON t.Id   = s.Id

    PRINT @@ROWCOUNT;

    SET @TrackId = (SELECT  MAX(Id) FROM @tempEmp)

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
```